# Не проходит сборка Cordova приложения, при попытке изменить AndroidManifest.xml через config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, web-intent

Я создаю Android-приложение используя Cordova. И хочу добавить возможность запускать своё приложение через URL. Приложение должно прочитать данные параметров этого URL, используя плагин `web-intent`. Я не хочу напрямую редактировать манифест. По этому я использую `edit-config`, в config.xml. Но проблема в том, что сборка крашится на некой задаче `:app:mergeDebugResources`. Если убрать `edit-config` то сборка проходит успешно. В чём может быть причина?

**config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mycool.app" 
        version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
>
    <name>App name</name>
    <description>App description</description>
    <author email="my-email@gmail.com" 
            href="https://my-site.com"
    >
        Author Name
    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#cfc463" />
        <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />

        <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" 
                     target="/manifest/application/activity"
                     mode="merge"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:sheme="https" android:host="myapp.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

**Плагины**

```
x-socialsharing
statusbar
com.borismus.webintent
```

**Логи**

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=E:\AndroidStudio\SDK (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=E:\AndroidStudio\SDK (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: E:\AndroidStudio\SDK
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED                                                                                                 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
42 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 31 up-to-date
```

**Версии**

```
OS: Windows 11 Pro
Cordova: 11.1.0
Java: openjdk 11 2018-09-25
Gradle: 7.5.1
```